# Why is ssh timing out on systems in the same network?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vpn

I'm using ssh to connect my laptop to my workplace computer, the command I'm using is:

```
ssh user@xx.xx.xx.xxx
```

The thing is, outside the workplace network, while using their vpn, it works perfectly, but while my laptop is connected to their network ssh runs for some time without feedback then gives the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xx.xxx port yy: Connection timed out
```

Anyone knows why this is and how to make it work? I'm running Arch Linux x86_64 on IdeaPad 3 if it matters.

Comment: Try pinging the server IP address whilst connected to their network to make sure the host is reachable. It's possible that firewall rules (or similar) make the host available to VPN clients but not clients on the LAN. Also, try adding some verbosity to your ssh command line by adding the '-v' (or -'vv') flag. If you post the results, we can see if it helps identify the issue

Comment: Yeah that seems about right, can't ping host either, thanks.